# Chrome Extension: chrome.storage.sync.get

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've created a simple extension that will store the current tab url address. I've used *chrome.storage.sync.set* to save the url however, when using *chrome.storage.sync.get* it pops up with random numbers rather than the URL address. I'm not exactly sure where it's even getting these numbers from? Any ideas?

Code bellow:

add.js

```
  var tabId = tab.id;
  tabUrl = tab.url;

 chrome.storage.sync.set({'urlLine': tabId}, function(){
  alert('URL has been added the database!');
```

view.js

```
  ....
  chrome.storage.sync.get('urlLine', function(data) {
    alert(data.urlLine);
```

Comment: `{'urlLine': tabUrl}`?

Comment: Man, you are storing tabId, how you can get tabUrl value.